# Is there a GetButtonpressed function?

Tags: c#, keyboard, xna, controllers

I'm using this to return a pressed key.

```
KeyboardState.GetPressedKeys();

if (KeyboardState.GetPressedKeys().Count() > 0)
{
     middlekick = KeyboardState.GetPressedKeys()[0];
}
```

Is there anything like that for pressed button?

As GamePadState.GetPressedButtons(); doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using the 'Buttons' property?
[read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepadstate.buttons.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Property Buttons of GamePadState structure is what you looking for, I suppose...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepadstate.buttons.aspx